# Convert Query String URL to Static Path

Tags: php, url, query-string

I am currently producing query string URLs when compressing images.

e.g. example.com/img.php?compressed=image.jpg&w=280

But I need to produce static URL paths.

e.g. example.com/img/image.jpg/width_280

I am using the following code to construct the query string URLs:

```
require_once 'img.class.php'; 

$getImage = new GetImage();
$getImage->setCacheFolder(FOLDER_CACHE);
$getImage->setErrorImagePath(FILEPATH_IMAGE_NOT_FOUND);
$getImage->setJpegQuality(JPEG_QUALITY);

$img = $_GET["img"];

$width = -1;
$width = isset($_GET["w"])?$_GET["w"]:-1;
$height = isset($_GET["h"])?$_GET["h"]:-1;

$type = "";
if(isset($_GET["exact"])) $type = GetImage::TYPE_EXACT;
else if(isset($_GET["exacttop"])) $type = GetImage::TYPE_EXACT_TOP;

$getImage->showImage($img,$width,$height,$type);
```

Is it possible to change this code in any way to produce static URLs?

It must be hard-coded, rather than a mod_rewrite solution.

Many thanks in advance!

B.

Comment: what do u mean by static url?

Comment: Sorry, I mean a URL path without QS. e.g. example.com/img/image.jpg/width_280

Comment: i don't believe this is going to be possible with out using mod_rewrite

Comment: You can try example.com/img.php/width_20/image.jpg - See $_SERVER for questioned url

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use mod_rewrite (can be in .htaccess if server config allows) or something like "ErrorDocument 404 /img.php", you can use path overloading (*I don't know if this has a name*):

**PHP:**

```
$subpath = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) + 1);

$parts  = explode('/', $subpath);
$opts = array(
    'width'  => -1,
    'height' => -1,
);
while ($parts) {
    if (preg_match('/^(width|height)_(\d+)$/', $parts[0], $matches)) {
        $opts[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
    // more options with "} elseif () {"
    } else {
        break;
    }
    array_shift($parts);
}
$image = implode('/', $parts);
if (!$image) {
    die("No image given\n");
}

// test output
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
var_dump($opts);
var_dump($image);
```

**Example:**

```
http://localhost/img.php/width_200/test/image.jpg
// Output
array(2) {
  ["width"]=>
  string(3) "200"
  ["height"]=>
  int(-1)
}
string(14) "test/image.jpg"
```

I've placed the image path at the end to have the real extension at the end. For the client side, the script name img.php is just another directory level.